How can I do a math operation to the result of "wc -l"?
I want to check the number of files inside a folder and I want the result to, for example, be multiplied by 4. I tried something like:
cd path/to/my/folder && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l | expr {} * 4

But it doesn't work. It works until:
cd path/to/my/folder && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l

But when I add something like "expr {} * 4", I get an error... I also tried other alternatives to "expr" but no luck so far.
BTW, I also want the result to be "pipeable" to another program, like ffmpeg, something like:
cd path/to/my/folder && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l | expr {} * 4 | ffmpeg -i {} out.mp4

The above is a silly example to simplify what I'm trying to do... For those curious, I'm using https://github.com/nihui/rife-ncnn-vulkan to quadruple the frames/framerate of a video, so I need to check the number of files (images) inside a folder, automatically multiply the number by 4 and put the result in the "-n" parameter of rife-ncnn-vulkan... So a more realistic command would be something like:
ffmpeg -i "video.mkv" -r 12 -c:v libwebp -lossless 1 -y input_frames/frame_%06d.webp && cd input_frames && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l | expr {} * 4 | rife-ncnn-vulkan -i input_frames -o output_frames -f %08d.webp -x -v -n {}

(notice the "{}" at the very end, where I want to place the result of the math operation).

BTW, I'm not sure you really need to use find or wc at all. For example, shopt -s nullglob; frames=( input_frames/*.webp ); frame_count=${#frames[@]} will store the number of matching names in frame_count without invoking either tool, and after you've done that, $(( frame_count * 4 )) will expand to the desired multiplier.

(if the shopt command gives an error, that means your shell isn't actually bash -- don't use sh to run bash scripts)

{} doesn't substitute input, it's just a string that'll be passed literally as an argument. But you can use xargs to capture input and pass it as argument(s). You can either use something like its -I{} to make it use {} (or any other string you happen to prefer) a placeholder for the input value, like this:
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l | xargs -I{} expr {} "*" 4

Or don't use a placeholder, in which case it'll add the captured input to the end of the command, so you need to rearrange the expression:
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l | xargs expr 4 "*"

Note that in either case, you must quote or escape the *, or else the shell will expand it to a list of filenames in the directory rather than passing it as a literal asterisk character.

It's worth being explicit (since this is being read by a beginner) that expr should generally be avoided in new code -- it's an artifact of the 1970s, from before shells had built-in math support. If one must use piped values (and thus xargs), then one needs an external command and expr is reasonable, but I'm not sure that this is actually a requirement as opposed to an accident of implementation.

Sorry for the late reply... After testing all options, this one is pretty much what I was looking for (with a tiny modification).
I know is not the most elegant or "up to date" way of doing things, but I was esentially looking for a simple, straightforward way of doing it and more importantly, I want to solve things with one-liners.

This works in bash and zsh:
cd path/to/my/folder
let count="$(find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | wc -l) * 4"
rife-ncnn-vulkan ... -n $count

The let command allows the shell to do arithmetic.
Update
Thank you to Charles Duffy for the suggestion. Here is a rewrite of the calculation:
count="$(( $(find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | wc -l) * 4 ))"


let is an artifact of shells from the 1980s. Modern POSIX-compliant arithmetic syntax -- which still works in ksh88 and its spiritual successors such as bash and zsh, but additionally is supported in ash, dash, and other POSIX sh implementations -- uses $(( )) instead.

I'm showing my age :)

Hey, thank you for the response... It sort of works!... sort of ... it's weird, when I run the command, it doesn't work... the first time.
Then, I pipe it to an "echo $count" to see what's happening and also, nothing... Then, I run it without piping it to anyhitng and then, once again, I run it piping it to the "echo $count" and it works... weird!

@CharlesDuffy could you elaborate on this?

@tuqueque, use set -x to turn on trace logging. That said, "piping to echo" is itself a problem: you shouldn't ever pipe to echo, as echo doesn't read from stdin so it ignores anything piped into it. The only pipe in this answer is the one between find and wc -- don't add more.

@tuqueque, ... The other thing to keep in mind about pipes is that each piece of a pipeline runs in a separate process from the other pieces, so if you set a variable in a pipeline component it's usually (subject to some exceptions that aren't important here) discarded after the pipeline exits. That's only relevant if you use pipes in places they aren't appropriate, so just be careful not to do that; only use pipes to connect the stdout of one process to the stdin of another.

Demonstrating how to apply the answer Hai Vu wrote to the code shown in the question:
ffmpeg \
  -i "video.mkv" \
  -r 12 \
  -c:v libwebp \
  -lossless 1 \
  -y input_frames/frame_%06d.webp || exit

count=$(( $(find input_frames -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | wc -l) * 4 )) || exit

rife-ncnn-vulkan -x -v \
  -i input_frames \
  -o output_frames \
  -f %08d.webp \
  -n "$count" || exit

Notice:

Instead of combining all our commands with &&, we're ending them with || exit; this has the same effect but is more maintainable.
We're not piping commands together. Pipes aren't needed for this, except between find and wc (and some versions of find have a -count action; if we used that, we wouldn't need wc either).
We're not running cd input_frames. If we did that it would change the directory the second copy of ffmpeg runs in, but you only want to change the directory find operates against -- we can do that by just changing . to input_frames.
We're storing count in a variable and using that variable later, not piping the value around.
Whitespace does a great deal to help readability.

